# First version of R Studio shinyBS package with bsModal()

Tags: r

Where can I get a version of the shinyBS package that includes the bsModal() function.  The version I have loaded on my machine does not have this function.  I really need it.  I am also having trouble locating documentation that includes bsModal().  Does this exist yet? I am assuming this is a relatively new functionality.

Comment: Have your tried its development website?

Comment: [Just go here](https://github.com/ebailey78/shinyBS) and follow the instructions to install the more up-to-date github version of the package.

Answer (score 1):

You will need shinyBS version 0.25 to get bsModal() or some other new features working. To do so you need to:

```
install_github("shinyBS", "ebailey78")
```

You will find the documentation related to bsModal() in the last tab of the [shinyBS demo](http://spark.rstudio.com/johnharrison/shinyBS-Demo/)

Even so you will get the bootstrap 2.3.2 modal and not the latest v3.3.1. If you need the latest version, you can source:

```
# Adding a bootstrap 3 modal dialog
bsModalBoot3 <- function (id, title, trigger, ..., href) 
{
  mo <- tags$div(class = "modal sbs-modal fade", id = id, 'data-trigger' = trigger, tabindex="-1", role="dialog", 'aria-labelledby'="myModalLabel", 'aria-hidden'="true",
                 tags$div(class = "modal-dialog", tags$div(class = "modal-content", tags$div(class = "modal-header", 
                                                                                             tags$button(type = "button", class = "close", 'data-dismiss' = "modal", 
                                                                                                         HTML("&times;")), tags$h3(class = "modal-title", id="myModalLabel", title)), body <- tags$div(class = "modal-body"), 
                                                           tags$div(class = "modal-footer", tags$a(href = "#", class = "btn", 
                                                                                                   'data-dismiss' = "modal", "Close")))))
  if (!missing(href)) {
    mo <- addAttribs(mo, 'data-remote' = href)
  }
  else {
    mo$children[[1]]$children[[1]]$children[[2]] <- tagAppendChildren(mo$children[[1]]$children[[1]]$children[[2]], 
                                                                      list = list(...))
  }
  return(mo)
}
```

You can look up the changes on my fork:

```
install_github("shinyBS", "Bolaka") - installs shinyBS vs 0.26
```

and call bsModalBoot3() to use the bootstrap 3.3.1 modal :)